# How do I graph $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$ without using graphing devices?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1}$$

How can I graph something like this without using graphing devices?

I equal $z = 0$ to find the graph on the xy plane. So I got a circle, $1=x^2 + y^2.$
But when I equal 0 for either the $x$ or the $y,$ I get $z = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$, but what's the graph of that? Different graphing websites were telling me different answers...

Please don't show some crazy and complicated methods to graph this. I just want simple steps just as plugging $x,y,z$ as zeroes and etc.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to plot this by hand? If you want to see what it looks like in 3D, just write "sqrt(x^2+y^2-1)" in Google.

Comment: You can't just see where your function is zero to get your surface. It would be like drawing a 2d plot only knowing where the function is 0 ... You can however see what your function would look like if you plug in $z=k$ and here you get $x^2+y^2=k^2+1$. Which is a circle centered on $0$ too, just not the same diameter as for $k=0$.

Comment: It's a quadric. These are three-dimensional conics. The non-generate ones are ellipsoids, paraboloids and hyperboloids. The way to find the shape is to look at how they meet the axes. So put $y=z=0$ and solve for $x$ to give the intersection points on the $x$-axis. It doesn't have any mixed terms or lower order terms so is centred at the origin, lined up with an axis.

Comment: Square both sides.  Your surface is a _quadric surface_.  They are classified into 5-7 types (I don't remember exactly how many).  As one of the answers states, yours is a _hyperboloid of one sheet_.  Your favorite calculus textbook should discuss this in detail and have pictures.  To sketch it, start be sketching some traces (interestions of the surface with the coordinate planes).  You found one of them, a circle in the $xy$-plane.  I think the other two traces are hyperbolas.  For this surface, you should also sketch the intersection of the surface with a few more horizontal planes .

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do is break a three-dimensional graph up into three separate planes, X-Y, X-Z, Y-Z, and I draw them individually and try to visualize how they fit together.

To graph the X-Y plane you set Z = 0 and plot the function as you normally would, so $$z = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2 - 1) == 0 = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$$
$$\text {Therefore:} x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
is your X-Y axis graph, which is just a circle of radius 1 centered at the origin.

Now onto the X-Z plane, we do this by setting y = 0.
$$z = \sqrt(x^2 - 1)$$
Which should be fairly trivial to plot (at least qualitatively).

And finally the Y-Z plane which will look exactly like the X-Z plane.
$$z = \sqrt(y^2 - 1)$$

So here are the three graphs (for visualization purposes... this is much easier on paper, though):

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$:

[image: Graph of x^2 + y^2 = 1]

$z = \sqrt(x^2 - 1)$:

[image: z = \sqrt(x^2 - 1)]

And finally:
$z = \sqrt(y^2 - 1)$

[image: z = \sqrt(x^2 - 1)]

Now the tricky part is to arrange these three planes so that the shape of the object can be inferred, here is how these three planes are arranged:

[image: Shamelessly stolen from google images...]

So all that's left to do is to imagine the graph on each of those axes and interpolate what the shape should be.

This is the graph Wolfram Alpha gives:

[image: z = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 - 1)]

Notice the circle of radius 1 on the X-Y plane and the hyperbolic curves on both the Y-Z plane and X-Z plane.

Comment: I think a good way to visualize it is to take your graph in the $xz$ plane and say "it is like this, revolved around the $z$ axis"

Comment: I didn't even realize that... That is a special case though, my solution can be used for slightly more general cases.

Answer (score 2):

If $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$ then $z^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 1$. Although the solution set of the first equation only gives part of the solution set of the second because $z^2=x^2 + y^2 - 1$ gives $z=\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$. We actually get the set $z^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ where $z\ge 0$. Let's consider $z^2 = x^2 + y^2 -1$.

Consider how the surface meets the axes. The $x$-axis has $y=z=0$. When $y=z=0$ we have $x^2-1=0$ and so $x = \pm 1$. The $y$-axis has $x=z=0$. When $x=z=0$ we have $y^2-1=0$ and so $y = \pm 1$. The $z$-axis has $x=y=0$. When $x=y=0$ we have $z^2=-1$ and there are no real solutions.  Hence we have a quadric surface which meets the $x$- and $y$-axis at two points and misses the $z$ axis. We have a hyperboloid of a single sheet (like a squashed cylinder).

For $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}$ we take the above hyperboloid and throw away the part with $z < 0$.

There is a more complicated method for not-so-simple examples. If you had lower-order and mixed terms, e.g. $xy$ or $2z$, then you complete the square to find the translation component. Then you find the matrix of the resulting quadratic form. The eigenvalues of this matrix tell you all about the surface and the way that it's oriented in three-space.

Comment: Thank you for the manifold solution whıch you have gave an answer 5minitues ago. I consider under your solution, and try to understand it. I have to delete this problem. Sorry for this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Your first step of checking the contour line for $z=0$ should give you a hint what to do otherwise:
The **contour line** for $z=c$ (with $c>0$) turns out to be a circle as well: $z=c\iff \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}=c\iff x^2+y^2=c^2+1$. That is a circle of radius $\sqrt{c^2+1}$.
Of course, $z<0$ does not occur because the square root is always non-negative. And also there is no $z$ value corresponding to $(x,y)$ with $x^2+y^2<1$, i.e. for points inside the unit disk.
The overall appearence of this graph is therefore like a cone with a widened hole at its apex.

Answer (score 0):

This particular equation is very easy to understand, because it’s a surface of revolution. Note that if we put $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the distance of a point from the $z$-axis, then your equation is $z = \sqrt{r^2-1}$. This means that no matter what plane $\Pi$ through the $z$-axis you draw, the intersection of your graph with $\Pi$ will look the same. And what’s that? It’s just *half* of a hyperbola, because your equation was not $z^2=r^2-1$, the more “geometric” form. So take the part of the hyperbola $z^2=x^2-1$ that’s above the $x,y$-plane, and rotate it through the $z$ axis. That’s your graph.

If I may say so, this *particular* problem falls much more easily to pure thought than to any graphing calculator.